# ODataClient MaxProtocolVersion V3

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata

I am trying to consume OData from a windows forms. So, what i have done to now is create a new project, i added a web service reference to the OData service and try to consume it.

My code is:

```
var VistaEntities = new VrExternalEntities("serviceURI");
var query = VistaEntities.VRtblCinemaType
            .Where(
                     x => 
                     x.VRtblCinema_Operators
                          .Any
                          (
                              z => 
                              z.VRtblSessions
                              .Any
                              (
                                   y => 
                                   y.Session_dtmDate_Time > DateTime.Now
                              )
                          )
                   )
             .Select
             (
                 x => 
                 new 
                 {
                     x.CinType_strCode, 
                     x.CinType_strDescription 
                 }
             );
```

If i remove the Where clause it works. If i do it says that Any is not supported. I know i have to set MaxProtocolVersion to V3 but i do not know how to do it. I don't have an entity context or anything else. I only have what i have stated above.

Please provide steps on how to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance.

Giannis

Comment: What version of the client are you using? (i.e., Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll)

Comment: I have added the nugget package. Microsoft.Data.Services.Client was added automatically. I had to remove the System one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must retrieve the [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of your [`DataService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646779%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and set the [`MaxProtocolVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataservicebehavior.maxprotocolversion%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of [its behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.dataservicebehavior%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to [`V3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.common.dataserviceprotocolversion%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

The best place to do this is certainly in the [InitializeService](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2008/06/16/so-special-initializeservice-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx) static method you can define in your service class, which will be given the proper configuration object as its `config` parameter by the environment.  It will only be invoked once, typically at the first request.

**Note #1:**  You need [WCF Data Services 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373845%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or greater.  The best way to get it is probably via the [`Server`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services/) [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) package.

**Note #2:**  Oddly enough, the [`DataServiceProtocolVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataservicebehavior.maxprotocolversion%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) type, although in the [`Common`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.common%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) namespace, is included in the Client assembly (`Microsoft.Data.Services.Client`, provided by the [`Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/) [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) package).  I suggested a better organization [here](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4260048-remove-dependency-from-the-server-to-the-client).

```
public class Vista : DataService<VistaContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule(...);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The client may indeed [specify the desired version in the requests](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/odata-core/#5_Versioning) by using the `DataServiceVersion` HTTP header. It's currently recommended that you specify and support a range of versions using the `MinDataServiceVersion` and `MaxDataServiceVersion` headers if you can, for obvious reasons.  Note however that the `MinDataServiceVersion` will be removed in [OData 4.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-4-0/) (see appendix E.1 of part 1 and "What's new" documents drafts).

The relevant documentation for the WCF Data Services 5.x implementation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473427%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). The documentation specific to the client seems pretty scarce, but looking at the reference you can see that you must use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh541123%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for the [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to specify the maximum protocol version, and it looks like you [cannot change it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.maxprotocolversion%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) at any one point for subsequent requests without rebuilding a new context. You may attempt to [fiddle with the headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258441%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) directly, but I wouldn't expect it to work reliably (or at all).

So, to answer your question, you really need control over how you create the context for the client.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. I was away the previous week and will be away this week too. When i am on that environment i will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am consuming this service and i am not responsible on extending it. So is it possible to do this on the client?